# How to make a bot kick someone if i say a certain keyword

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So if I say for example 'abracadraba' I want the bot to kick a certain member.
I know the player I want to kick for example 'example#1234'
The bot has all permisions necessary.

This is the code by now:

```
import discord
import time
from discord.ext import commands

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Botu e gata")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("ba"):
        await member.kick(userName = "FluXon#5183",reason=None)


    if "matei" in message.content:
        await message.channel.send("Suge carasu") 
    if "Matei" in message.content:
        await message.channel.send("El e ceo nostru")
        time.sleep(2)
        await message.channel.send("Unul dintre cei mai respectati cetateni ai acestui server")
        time.sleep(2)
        await message.channel.send("El se ocupa de chestii ca voi sa nu trebuiasca sa va ocupati")
        time.sleep(2)
        await message.channel.send("Asa ca respecta           ti-l")
        time.sleep(2)
        await message.channel.send("MATEI CEO")
        await message.channel.send("MATEI CEO")
        await message.channel.send("MATEI CEO")
        







client.run(token)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My kick command lets anyone in the server kick someone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64191656/my-kick-command-lets-anyone-in-the-server-kick-someone)

Answer (score 0):

Below is some code which will achieve what you want, make sure to replace `123456789` with the ID of the user you want to be kicked. You can find a users id by following [this](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/206346498-Where-can-I-find-my-User-Server-Message-ID-) tutorial.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if "abracadraba" in message.content:
        member = await message.guild.fetch_member(123456789)
        await member.kick()
```

**Note:**

Anyone could kick this member by saying the word, not just you. If you want to limit it to only yourself, you can check the `message.author` is equal to you. This function will also raise a `discord.Forbidden` if the bot doesn't have the permission to kick someone.

### Relevant Documentation:

- [discord.Guild.fetch_member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=fetch_member#discord.Guild.fetch_member)
- [discord.Member.kick](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=fetch_member#discord.Member.kick)